# Use calling method as parameter in ruby

Tags: ruby, parameters

Sorry if it isn't that expresive, but I really can't figure out how to title this question. The thing is like this:

I have to run this test:

```
Aspects.where has_parameters(3, 'optional')
```

I have this method:

```
def self.has_parameters(amount, status = 'everything')
   if status == 'mandatory'
     ***.parameters.select do |param| param.first == :req end.size == amount
   elsif status == 'optional'
     ***.parameters.select do |param| param.first == :opt end.size == amount
   elsif status == 'everything'
     ***.parameters.size == amount
   end
end
```

Aspects is the class that has both methods (where and has_parameters)

And a "where" method that lets pretend that returns a method (:symbol)

The problem is with replacing the *** with the method that "where" returns us.

So it would be like this:
    Aspects.where will leave us, for example :singleton_method.. And I need to somehow make has_parameters to know that :singleton_method is the ***

Thank you!!! Any question just ask!!

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking. What is `parameters` and where does it come from? Perhaps if you included an example of usage. As it stands, the syntax you're after (`.where has_parameters(3, 'optional')`) really makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to build a fluent call chain (and I give up understanding the blocks `do |param| ...`) you can store the last value returned by `where` in a class field `@@current_method`

```
class Aspects

  @@current_method

  def self.where(p)
    @@current_method = p.blah()
  end

  def self.has_parameters(amount, status = 'everything')
   if status == 'mandatory'
     @@current_method.parameters {|p| ... }
  end
end
```